# Time complexity exceeding while using "else-if" but works fine when using "If statement"

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-loops, time-limiting

ques: Given an array of integers in increasing order, return an array containing positions(index+1) of two numbers that add up to a specific target number

Sol: When I  write the code without using else-if for checking second condition, then I get the desired result:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        int left=0;
        int right=numbers.length-1;
        int arr[]=new int[2];
        while(left<right)
        {
            if(numbers[left]+numbers[right]==target)
            {
                arr[0]=left+1;
                arr[1]=right+1;
            }
             if(numbers[left]+numbers[right]<target)
            {
                left++;
            }
            else
                right--;
        }
        return arr;
        
    }
}
```

But when I am using else-if instead of "if" for checking the second condition, then the time limit is exceeded. Can anyone explain the reason behind this:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        int left=0;
        int right=numbers.length-1;
        int arr[]=new int[2];
        while(left<right)
        {
            if(numbers[left]+numbers[right]==target)
            {
                arr[0]=left+1;
                arr[1]=right+1;
            }
             else if(numbers[left]+numbers[right]<target) // using else if
            {
                left++;
            }
            else
                right--;
        }
        return arr;
        
    } }
```

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is incorrect. You should use `break;`, when you find the result in order to get out of while loop. Otherwise, you will get into infinite loop, since you will not change the `left` and `right`.

Updated solution:

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    int left=0;
    int right=numbers.length-1;
    int arr[]=new int[2];
    while(left<right)
    {
        if(numbers[left]+numbers[right]==target)
        {
            arr[0]=left+1;
            arr[1]=right+1;
            break;
        }
         else if(numbers[left]+numbers[right]<target) // using else if
        {
            left++;
        }
        else
            right--;
    }
    return arr;
    
} }
```